# ERB Javascript conditional error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run the following lines in my Rails app in an erb file:

```
<script>
  if("<%=current_user%>".length>0){
    console.log('set mixpanel current user');
    mixpanel.identity("<%=current_user.id%>");
  }else{
    console.log('set mixpanel identity to 0');
    mixpanel.identify('0');
  }
</script>
```

I am getting errors with the line containing `<%=current_user.id%>`, which seems to be analyzed even if the conditional is not satisfied:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 8 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

How do I handle a javascript conditional with a ruby variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In erb file, we can embed ruby code using scriptlets: `<% %>`.

This should work:

```
<script>
  <% if current_user %>
    console.log('set mixpanel current user');
    mixpanel.identity("<%=current_user.id%>");
  <% else %>
    console.log('set mixpanel identity to 0');
    mixpanel.identify('0');
  <% end %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` instead of `"<%=current_user%>".length>0` would work I guess.